# Android Studio / Flutter luck of camera footage

Tags: flutter, android-studio, asynchronous, camera

I've tried to make a view for my flutter app for taking photos.
It compiles, but the screen is white and I'm not sure if it's the code's or the emulator's problem.
[That's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T83LC.png)
I followed a tutorial to program it and am confused as to why it doesn't work.

```
    List<CameraDescription> cameras=[];
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
```

```
    class _CameraView extends State<CameraView> {
      late CameraController _controller;
      late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;
      void _navigateToNewPage(BuildContext context, Widget page) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: page,
          );
        }));
      }
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _controller=CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
        _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
      }
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar:AppBar(
            title: StandardAppBar(),
          ),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                future: _initializeControllerFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){
                  return CameraPreview(_controller);
                }
                else{
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                }
              }),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0.0,
                      child: Container(
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                            _navigateToNewPage(context, Scaffold(
                              appBar: AppBar(
                                title: StandardAppBar(),
                              ),
                              body:
                                MyCustomForm()
                            ));
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.panorama_fisheye, color: MyApp.myCustomColor,),
                      )
                      )
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
       );
      }
    }
```

I changed the cameras in emulated device, to see if they aren't the problem.
It didn't help.